# Is it possible to convert a numpy int64 array to type int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, int

I am trying to convert a numpy array of 64 bit integers into an array of standard python integers (i.e., variables of type `int`).

In my naive thinking I believed that `np.int64` represents the 64 bit integer and `int` represents the standard python integer but that doesn't seem to be correct:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(2)
print(a.dtype)  # dtype('int64')
print(type(a[0]))  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
b = a.astype(int)
print(b.dtype)  # dtype('int64')
print(type(b[0]))  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
c = a.astype('int')
print(c.dtype)  # dtype('int64')
print(type(c[0]))  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

One thing that works of course is:

```
d = a.tolist()
print(type(d[0]))  # int
```

Is it possible to have a numpy array with numbers of type `int` or does numpy require the variables to be of its equivalent `np.int` datatypes?

Comment: Yes, the built-in `int` isn't a valid dtype. It will be converted to whatever `np.int_` is, which may be `np.int64` or `np.int32` depending on your platform. You can use `object`, but *why on earth would you want to do this?*

Comment: Numpy uses own data types. You can check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html.

Comment: `I am trying to convert a numpy array of 64 bit integers into an array of standard python integers` Why?

Comment: @RafaelC guess he wants to store numbers greater than 64 bit.

Comment: Your thinking is correct, that `int` represents the standard python `int` type. Really, you could make an argument that the `numpy.array` constructor should throw an error if you pass that to the `dtype` argument, but for whatever reason, the creators of `numpy` decided "Oh, that must mean you want the corresponding `numpy` dtype". It does cut down on some keystrokes...

Comment: @RafaelC not every python lib knows how to deal with `np.int64` automatically. I was curious if there's a way to have a `np.array` of dtype `int` or if that's simply impossible.

Comment: @FLekschas what? But *numpy* does. Why would you want to use `numpy` with the `int` type? Again, you *can*, but you must use `dtype=object`. This essentially removes the advantages of numpy to give you a crappy Python list (with poorer performance characteristics!)

Comment: You can use numpy for whatever calculations, and parse only the portion you'll input in these other libs as ints (using standard `map(int, array)`or w/e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is merely a repost of the comments to close the question.*

> The built-in `int` isn't a valid dtype. It will be converted to
>   whatever `np.int_` is, which may be `np.int64` or `np.int32` depending
>   on your platform. You can, but you must use dtype=object, which
>   essentially removes the advantages of numpy to give you a Python list.

By *juanpa.arrivillaga*